# How to change the selected item color in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: themes, gtk

How do I change the default orange to something else? Upon the update, the dconf setting has ceased to work. I can change certain apps (gtk-2) using GNOME Color Chooser, but other apps like Libre Office, Gedit, and Nautilus are still orange.

Answer (score 0):

Everything except the color of nautilus can be changed using:

**Option 1**

Replace the orange color in Ubuntu

Install `dconf-editor`

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Start the program press Alt+F2 and then write `dconf-editor` and enter.

**Path: org => gnome => desktop => interface**
Find the line **“gtk-color-scheme”** and add this string:

```
bg_color:#f0f1f2;selected_bg_color:#023C88
```

Here it is then simply choose the color you want yourself, I have adark blue color, then just replace the last color in the string (#023C88) to change the highlight color to what you want.

**Option 2**

Right now, there is no way to change theme colors from the GUI as in previous versions. However, if you are desperate, you can change the color values in the following files to your desired color:

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

Thanks goes to kolinab for this.